# Openlayer 5 - Query style color gives wrong result

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap, geojson, openlayers-5

i have a OSM with a vector layer (three circles with locations loaded from a GEOJSON file). Clicking on a feature (circle) causes a color change of the circle. That work's fine:

```
map.on('click', function (e) {
  var pixel = map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
  map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function (feature) {
    style1 = new ol.style.Style({image: new ol.style.Circle( ({ radius: 10, fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: '#3ED120' }) }))
        });

       if (feature) {
          console.info(style.getImage().getFill().getColor());          
          feature.setStyle(style1);
        } 
     });
   });
```

So, I checked the color of the circle before changing. The result is correct (it's red: #ff0000). Clicking on the circle again I expect the resulting color is "#3ED120", but console.info show it's still "#ff0000", although the circle on the map change his color on the first click from red to green (#3ED120).

What's wrong? Do I have to do a refresh of the layer?

Info: I want to read out the color of the circle for a query, if the circle has already been pressed (that's when the circle is already green).

Comment: where did you define 'style' in your console.info? You should probably do feature.getStyle() instead, to get the current style of your feature

Comment: feature.getStyle() i already tested. works correctly when i place this after the setStyle(). Otherwise get the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getImage' of null". I need to read out the color before setting the setStyle().

Comment: Where did you define the original 'style' (=red)? if you did this on the layer, the features themselves don't have a style (hence is null), until you set the style of the feature in your click function. If a feature style is set, openlayers uses that instead of the layer style.
If that is the case, try styling all features 'red', instead of the layer.

Comment: Yes Rob, i define the style on the vector layer: var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({style: function(feature) { style.getText().setText(feature.get('name')+ ' ' +feature.get('days')); return style; }}); -- i added there "feature.setStyle(style);" and now it work's as aspected. But the text is all the same. I think something was overwrite with setStyle.

Comment: in your case, setting the style via a stylefunction seems like a little overkill. If you set the style to a function, the function is called every single time the feature gets rendered(every pan, every zoom, etc). You could just set the style the old fashioned way once, maybe when the data is loaded. This might increase the performance and also makes the code clearer

Comment: Any ideas why my "feature.setStyle(style)" overwrites the style.getText().setText(feature.get('name')). On all circles appear the same name. Is there a workaround? I will set the red style to all markes and also the text of the GEOJSON should be labeled.

Comment: Are you using a stylefunction or are you setting the style via setters? if you set the style via setters, it could looks something like features.forEach(feature => {var name = feature.get('name'); var style = new Style [[[  insert ALL style definitions (including text) here  ]]]; feature.setStyle(newStyle) }).  Do the same on click (including the text)

Comment: i use ist so: var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({style: function(feature) { feature.setStyle(style); style.getText().setText(feature.get('name')+ ' ' +feature.get('days')); return style; }}); Results in all the same text at the map.

Comment: you should either use a stylefunction,returning a style, or set the style of the feature, but right now you are doing both, which could lead to some things being overwritten

Comment: ok, that helps. style: function(feature) { var style = new ol.style.Style({ text: new ol.style.Text({  text: feature.get('name')  }), image: new ol.style.Circle( ({ radius: 10, fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: '#ff0000' }) })) }); feature.setStyle(style); } ..At the end i only set the style of the features. Thanks.